# Confused with function-object usage in Python

Tags: python, function, object, parameters

Am currently learning python using "Think Python" in which i came through a certain piece of code like below and am being a beginner programmer i don't understand how it works, explain me the code below and also the various concepts behind it.

excercise: A function object is a value you can assign to a variable or pass as an argument. For
example, do_twice is a function that takes a function object as an argument and calls it twice:

```
def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

# Here’s an example that uses do_twice to call a function named print_spam twice.

def print_spam():
    print 'spam'

do_twice(print_spam)
```

this code gives o/p as
spam
spam
i dont know how and i want deeper explanation with this concept

Comment: What is your question?  What do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python functions are first-class objects. Just like other objects, they can be assigned to variables and passed around.

```
>>> def print_spam():
...     print 'spam'
... 
>>> print_spam
<function print_spam at 0x105722ed8>
>>> type(print_spam)
<type 'function'>
>>> another_name = print_spam
>>> another_name
<function print_spam at 0x105722ed8>
>>> another_name is print_spam
True
>>> another_name()
spam
```

In the above example session I play around with the `print_spam` function object, assigning it to `another_name`, then invoking it via that other variable.

All that the code you quoted from Think Python does is pass `print_spam` as a parameter to the function `do_twice`, which calls it's parameter `f` twice.

Comment: still am not clear why and how they are using that f()

Comment: `f` is a parameter of the function `do_twice()`. By giving that function a reference to another function, `f` becomes a reference to that other function. Adding `()` then calls the referenced function.

Comment: Ya i got it finally.

        print_spam = f
and inside do_twice

        f() = print_spam()

Thanks to Martijn Pieters